Why soft Bellman backup operator is converged in tabular settings?
This comes from Soft Actor-Critic:Off-Policy Maximum Entropy Deep Reinforcement Learning with a Stochastic Actor.
Consider the soft Bellman backup operator$\tau^{\pi}$ in equation and a mapping $Q^{0}: S \times A \to \mathbb{R} 
 $ with $\left| \mathcal{A}   \right| < \infty$, and define $Q^{k+1} = \tau^{\pi}Q^{K}$. Then the sequence $Q^{k}$ will converge to the soft Q-value of $\pi$ as $k\to\infty$.
$$
\tau^{\pi}Q(s_{t}, a_{t})\triangleq r(s_{t}, a_{t}) + \gamma\mathbb{E}_{s_{t+1} \sim p} [V(s_{t+1})]
$$
where
$$
V(s_{t}) = \mathbb{E}_{a_{t}\sim \pi}[Q(s_{t}, a_{t}) - \log\pi(a_{t}|s_{t})]
$$

The proof is confusing me.
What's the standard convergence result for policy evaluation and why this is converged?

In Soft Actor-Critic the convergence of the iterative process is based on the principle of temporal difference (TD) learning and the properties of the soft Bellman backup operator. Specifically the algo aims to minimize the TD error via the soft Bellman backup operator $T^\pi$ (defined in Equation 2 of your reference) between successive estimates of the above LHS Q-function and its corresponding value function. Therefore it seems here the author is referring to S&B book's standard TD learning convergence result by stochastic bootstrap approximation as stated in page 124:

can we still guarantee convergence to the correct answer? Happily, the answer is yes. For any fixed policy $\pi$, TD(0) has been proved to converge to $v_\pi$, in the mean for a constant step-size parameter if it is sufficiently small, and with probability $1$ if the step-size parameter decreases according to the usual stochastic approximation conditions (2.7).

